# ERROR org.apache.thrift.server.TSimpleServer - Error occurred during processing of message

Tags: java, c#, exception, thrift

I'm using Thrift (Java server, C# client).
I get this error **Thrift.Transport.TTransportException** .  I've been debugging and my program stopped at:

```
   TMessage msg = iprot_.ReadMessageBegin();
```

in C# method **recv_getCopii()**  in Service generated by thrift:

```
public List<Copil> getCopii(Proba proba)
{
  #if !SILVERLIGHT
  send_getCopii(proba);
  return recv_getCopii();

  #else
  var asyncResult = Begin_getCopii(null, null, proba);
  return End_getCopii(asyncResult);

  #endif
}
#if SILVERLIGHT
public IAsyncResult send_getCopii(AsyncCallback callback, object state, Proba proba)
#else
public void send_getCopii(Proba proba)
#endif
{
  oprot_.WriteMessageBegin(new TMessage("getCopii", TMessageType.Call, seqid_));
  getCopii_args args = new getCopii_args();
  args.Proba = proba;
  args.Write(oprot_);
  oprot_.WriteMessageEnd();
  #if SILVERLIGHT
  return oprot_.Transport.BeginFlush(callback, state);
  #else
  oprot_.Transport.Flush();
  #endif
}

public List<Copil> recv_getCopii()
{
  TMessage msg = iprot_.ReadMessageBegin();
  if (msg.Type == TMessageType.Exception) {
    TApplicationException x = TApplicationException.Read(iprot_);
    iprot_.ReadMessageEnd();
    throw x;
  }
  getCopii_result result = new getCopii_result();
  result.Read(iprot_);
  iprot_.ReadMessageEnd();
  if (result.__isset.success) {
    return result.Success;
  }
  if (result.__isset.ce) {
    throw result.Ce;
  }
  throw new TApplicationException(TApplicationException.ExceptionType.MissingResult, "getCopii failed: unknown result");
}
```

And I get this errors in Java:

```
    18717 [main] ERROR org.apache.thrift.server.TSimpleServer - Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at concurs.server.ConcursService$getCopii_result$getCopii_resultStandardScheme.write(ConcursService.java:4287)
    at concurs.server.ConcursService$getCopii_result$getCopii_resultStandardScheme.write(ConcursService.java:4226)
    at concurs.server.ConcursService$getCopii_result.write(ConcursService.java:4172)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:55)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TSimpleServer.serve(TSimpleServer.java:80)
    at concurs.StartObjectServer.main(StartObjectServer.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
18717 [main] WARN org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport - Error closing output stream.
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.close(TIOStreamTransport.java:110)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.close(TSocket.java:235)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TSimpleServer.serve(TSimpleServer.java:102)
    at concurs.StartObjectServer.main(StartObjectServer.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: What have you tried doing to debug?  It seems that `java.lang.NullPointerException` is the issue?

Comment: Java code is throwing exception. Looks like C# client is not sending proper which is expected by Java server. Did you analyze logs on Java server to see what field or property is null and causing the error?

Comment: The problem is with that function **getCopii()** because if I create a new object, a mock list and I sent it to Client, it works... the problem is with `TMessage msg = iprot_.ReadMessageBegin(); `

Comment: @Dana: No, you're wrong. The problem is **not** with `TMessage msg = iprot_.ReadMessageBegin();`. Look at the first line in your error log, it clearly says `18717 [main] ERROR org.apache.thrift.server.TSimpleServer - Error occurred during processing of message.java.lang.NullPointerException` -- the C# error is only the result of the server closing the connection prematurely **because of that server-side NPE**. If the NPE occurs because the client sends invalid data - well, that's how life is. Better get prepared for the fact that clients will call your APIs in weird ways.

Comment: Thank for your answers, I solved the problem.. I had a row in database with id = -1 .. And that's why I got NullPointerException.